# How do I copy Outlook calendar information (Office 365) into Google calendar?

Tags: google-calendar, office-365, outlook-on-the-web

I am getting lots of results on related questions, but not quite what I want.

I have Outlook Office 365 from some organization, and a Gmail account. What I want is, for example, once a day or even continuously COPY information from the Outlook account INTO the Google calendar account, but NOT the other way around (not "sync"). Of course, if something is deleted from the Outlook, it should be deleted on Google calendar, but again -- it goes only ONE way, changes made on Gmail shouldn't be copied to Outlook Office 365.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

If you want your Outlook Calendar one-way synced to your Google Calendar (gCal) then this project may work for you:

**GAS-ICS-Sync**
https://github.com/derekantrican/GAS-ICS-Sync

You will need to configure your Outlook calendar for sharing then use its shareable link as the calendar feed in the Google Apps Script.

The script includes the ability to assign a custom color to the synced events so you can tell them apart from your other gCsl events, and you can optionally also prepend some text to the event names (E.G "From Outlook:".

If you remove an event in Outlook it will automatically remove it from gCal, and if you accidentally delete a synced event from your dCal, it will be recreated automatically on the next sync  a few minutes later.